# Hey Ive got 2 [not_required_arguments] problems 1 on return MaterialApp( and the other on Scaffold(

Tags: visual-studio, dart, flutter

I've got 2 [not_required_arguments] on Visual Studio Code with Flutter problems 1 on `return MaterialApp(` and the other on `Scaffold(`. Please can anyone help?

I've tried searching around but didn't find much that actually helped solve the issue.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() => runApp(MyApp(

    ));

    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyAppState();
    }

    class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData(
            // Define the default Brightness and Colors
            brightness: Brightness.dark,
            primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue[800],
            accentColor: Colors.cyan[600],
          )
        , home: SafeArea(
             child: Scaffold(
               drawer: new Drawer(
                 child: new ListView(

                 ) ,
               ),
                body: new Center(
                  child: new Column(
                    children: <Widget>[],
              ))),
            )
        );
      }
    }
```

This is the full message of both problems:

```js
{
  "resource": "/Users/camillebasbous/first_app/lib/main.dart",
  "owner": "dart",
  "code": "not_enough_required_arguments",
  "severity": 8,
  "message": "1 required argument(s) expected, but 0 found.",
  "source": "dart",
  "startLineNumber": 19,
  "startColumn": 23,
  "endLineNumber": 19,
  "endColumn": 508,
  "tags": []
}
```

Comment: Can you please share some more details, what the exact problem is?

Comment: `not_required_arguments` is not clear to me what that means. Please add the full error output and what location in the code causes this error.